# When i'm running create-creat-app <projectName> getting below error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

whenever i'm trying to create react app, getting below error.

E:\reactjs\udemy_max>npx create-react-app react-app

Creating a new React app in E:\reactjs\udemy_max\react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall E:\reactjs\udemy_max\react-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall E:\reactjs\udemy_max\react-app\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall E:\reactjs\udemy_max\react-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- cra-template@1.0.3
- react-dom@16.13.1
- react@16.13.1
- react-scripts@3.4.1
  added 1623 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1627 packages in 51.673s

57 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: U can use "Yarn" instead of npx
```yarn create react-app react-app```
Note: yarn is installed in your system

Comment: Yes, tried using "yarn create react-app react-app" but only node_module and package.json file gets created

Comment: thanks @rashijain, Issue got resolved after disabling anti-virus scanner.

Comment: great @Vicky Kumar